# Finding all partitions (2 elements per subset) of a set composed of an even number of elements

Tags: list-manipulation, education, partitions

I'd like to find all the partitions (each subset of a partition should contain 2 elements) of a set composed by an even number of elements. For example, given $A=\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace$, I'd like to see the partitions:

$$
\lbrace \lbrace 1,2 \rbrace, \lbrace 3,4 \rbrace, \lbrace 5,6 \rbrace \rbrace
\\
\lbrace \lbrace 1,3 \rbrace, \lbrace 2,4 \rbrace, \lbrace 5,6 \rbrace \rbrace
\\
\ldots
$$

etc.

Comment: Perhaps ```Partition[#,2]&/@Permutations@Range@6```?

Comment: Hi @Hausdorff can you post an answer with the needed code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too complex ,but work.

```
result6 = 
 Sort /@ (Map[
      Sort] /@ (Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[Range[6]])) // 
  DeleteDuplicates
result6//Length
Grid[result6, Dividers -> {False, All}]
```

> `15`

[image]

```
result8 = 
  Sort /@ (Map[
       Sort] /@ (Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[Range[8]])) // 
   DeleteDuplicates;
reslut8//Length
Grid[Partition[result8, 3], Dividers -> {All, All}]
```

> `105`

For general `n=2k`,the answer should be `(n-1)!!`,but I don't know how to list it in a simple way.

```
Table[(2 k - 1)!!, {k, 1, 5}]
```

> `{1, 3, 15, 105, 945}`

Comment: Hello @cvgmt thank you very much for your helpful answer. The second part of the code is about which case?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi For  `n=8` there are `(n-1)!!=7!!=7*5*3*1=105` partitions.

Comment: yes and also the result8 code.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[addPair, pairPartitions]

addPair[n_][{parts : {_, _} ..}] := Append[{parts}, #] & /@ 
  Subsets[Complement[Range @ n, parts], {2}]

pairPartitions[n_] := DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort] @
  Nest[Catenate @* Map[addPair[n]], List /@ Thread[{1, Range[2, n]}], n/2 - 1]
```

***Examples:***

```
pairPartitions[6] // Grid[#, Dividers -> {None, All}]&
```

[image]

```
Length @ pairPartitions[#] & /@ {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 15, 105, 945, 10395}
> ```

Comment: perfect, very nice!

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[twoPartitions]
twoPartitions[n_] := Select[Union@@# == Range[n]&]@Fold[Subsets, Range@n, {{2}, {n/2}}]
```

***Examples:***

```
twoPartitions[6] // Grid[#, Dividers -> {None, All}]&
```

[image]

```
Length @ twoPartitions[#] & /@ {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
```

> ```
>  {1, 3, 15, 105, 945}
> ```

Comment: Ciao @kglr can you organize the result in a table as in the cvgmt answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Something much more efficient with a brain teasing code.

```
Clear[pairs]
pairs[0] = {{}};
pairs[n_] := 
 Flatten[(d |-> 
     Prepend[Partition[Complement[Range[n], d][[Flatten@#]], 2], 
        d] & /@ pairs[n - 2]) /@ ({1, #} & /@ Rest@Range[n]), 1]
```

Timings:

```
Table[Length[pairs[n]] // Timing, {n, 0, 14, 2}] // Column
```

---

```
{0.,1}
{0.,1}
{0.,3}
{0.,15}
{0.015625,105}
{0.046875,945}
{0.625,10395}
{8.53125,135135}
```